# git revert <from>..<to> - what is REALLY reverted?

Tags: git, git-revert

git-revert documentation says:

```
git revert -n master~5..master~2
```

Revert the changes done by commits from the **`fifth`** last commit in master (included) to the **third** last commit in master (included)

But my observation shows something different.
After the call:

```
git revert HEAD~1..HEAD
```

The last commit is removed instead of the previous one.

So I'd say that:

```
git revert -n master~5..master~2
```

reverts the changes done by commits from the **fourth** last commit in master (included) to the **`second`** last commit in master (included).

Other example: **`git revert HEAD`** reverts last commit - this is ok

But **`git revert HEAD..`** says that given list is empty - I'd expect that it reverts last commit as well since documentation says that left boundary is included.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Let's make some order in your question.

Before we start lets have some terminology

#### `Terminology`

[What is HEAD in depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716)

```
HEAD    = Current commit 
../ ... = Commit range (from ... to)
revert  = Undo the given change
```

---

#### ***`git revert -n master~5..master~2`***

> Revert the changes done by commits from the fifth last commit in master (included) to the third last commit in master (included)

You are using range. The range is ***from...to***, in your case from 5 to 2 (not including).

---

> `git revert HEAD~1..HEAD`
> The last commit is removed instead of the previous one.

You are telling git this: Please revert the content in the range of the `previous commit up to the last one` so its **undo** the changes from the previous commit [not included] `HEAD~1` up to the current commit `HEAD`

---

> Other example: `git revert HEAD` reverts last commit - this is ok

In this case you are giving a **single** SHA-1 (`HEAD`) so its reverting the given commit. Its the same as reverting any other commit in the history.

```
# revert commit XYZ
git revert XYX

# revert the current commit (git will extract the HEAD SHA-1)
# (Again read the linked post above to fully understand what is HEAD)
git revert HEAD
```

---

> But ***`git revert HEAD..`*** says that given list is empty

As explained above `..` stands for a range. You supplied the only one side of the list (missing from/ to depends how you look on it)

If we will go back to this: ***`git revert -n master~5..master~2`*** what that happening behind the scenes is something like this:

```
 for (index=first SHA-1 to index= last SHA-1)
     git revert SHA-1


  git revert -n master~5..master~2 ->

     git revert -master~5
     git revert -master~4
     git revert -master~3
```